# "Pardon, O King!"

Tags: meaning

> "Pardon, **O** King!" cried the little mouse. "Forgive me this time. I shall never repeat it and I shall never forget your kindness. And who knows, I may be able to do you a good turn one of these days!” [The Lion and the Mouse](http://www.kidsworldfun.com/shortstories_lionandmouse.php)

What is this letter "O" in the "Pardon, O King!"? what the meaning of it?

Comment: See here for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case#English.

Comment: So it doesn't mean "oh"? Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"O" is a form of direct address not used much in contemporary English speech. It survives mainly in texts from prior centuries. Occasions for its use included addressing a mighty ruler, a beloved, or a crowd.

We might hear a vestige of it when an adult addresses a toddler, "O you little cutie" or "O little one", or when someone calls to a person in another room:

> O Bobbie, please come downstairs to the livingroom. We want
>   to speak with you.